# Change the value of a cell based on the hidden value of another cell

Tags: ssrs

On a 2012 SSRS report I have the following:

[image: image1]

You can see that "Site", 0098110, has a total of 13 "tests" associated with it. This is what I want to show while the group is in the collapsed state.

When I expand the group you can see the number of specific services - 9 "ABC" services, and 4 "XYZ" services. This accounts for the total of 13. Naturally there is a row grouping of Site Name, Service Type, Site Fee and Tests.

What I want is for the Total column to remain visible, but for its value to be set to blank (null) when a specific group is expanded like below instead of the image of the expanded group above:

[image: image2]

...but the total for the group should reappear when the group is again collapsed, like in image 1. If I can simply make the Total cell blank based on the hidden value of the Service Type cell I'd be good.

I've combed the site and can't find anything specifically like this problem. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried visibility toggle on those textboxes when the based on site name?

Comment: That's what I thought of Antoine but I can't find where or how to find setting the visibility of specific text boxes - only the entire column as a group.

Comment: Let me see if I can find it...

Comment: I'm using latest SSDT so not sure if it's exactly the same. On textbox you want to hide, right-click on it and select Textbox Properties. Then you should see Visibility on the options on left. Click Visibility and pick display option when report intiially run. Click check box on same page to pick the item that can toggle the visibility.

Comment: Thanks Antoine. I'm busy all day today with meetings but I will attempt this evening and let you know. Appreciated.

Comment: can you just add "Above Total" for the "site name" group in this table.?